# Position element with a left value and have it shift further to the left when it overflows its parent

Tags: javascript, css

I have page with a container and a menu where each menu-item has a submenu. The menu is inside the container. The submenu should be positioned so that its left side aligns with the left side of the parent menu-item. However if the submenu is so wide that it it would overflow the container (or break its contents) the menu should be positioned further to the left instead.

Is that possible with pure CSS or do you need JS for this?

Answer (score 0):

Could you fix it to the right of the container instead? It would then have a variable left.

Comment: That wouldn't work, the submenu should be aligned with its parent menuitem by default.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... Could you possibly post your CSS and HTML?